# convertir resultado de consulta Mysql a INT

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Si tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
    function obtener_id(){
    $conn = db_connect();
    $query = "SELECT max(idproblema) FROM problemas";
    $result = @$conn->query($query);    
    return $result; 
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero hacer es que lo que me regrese esa consulta sea el numero marcado en la imagen ya siendo un INT...
por ejemplo que $result solo sea un 1, esta consulta la hago para saber el ultimo id de la tabla.

quiero que result me quede como un numero, no lo quiero asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que buscas, pero por lo que entiendo tambien te puede servir usar `COUNT`, en vez de `MAX`

Comment: podrías darnos mas detalles de la tabla

Comment: listo espero asi quede mas claro

Comment: SELECT idproblema FROM problemas ORDER BY idproblema DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, no veo en tu código que estés asciendo **fecth_array ** y cuando lo coloques  te recomiendo que le coloques un alias al **max(idproblema)** por ejemplo así   **max(idproblema) AS idmax**

Comment: no habia conocia el fecth_array muchas gracias... y la consulta que me dan ahi lo que pasa es que no me convierte a INT el resultado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo escribiría una función que sea segura (*safe*), del siguiente modo:

```
function obtener_id(){
    $conn = db_connect();
    $query = "SELECT max(idproblema) maximo FROM problemas";
    $result = $conn->query($query);

    $maximo=0;

    if ($result) {
        $fila = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $maximo = ($result->num_rows === 0) ? 0 :  $fila["maximo"];
    }
    return (int) $maximo;
}
```

En la misma he contemplado la siguiente lógica:

- Dar de entrada el valor `0` a la variable `$maximo`
- Verificar si la consulta fue exitosa. Si lo ha sido, entonces procedo a asignar el valor
- Le he dado el alias `maximo` a la columna resultante del `SELECT`, para luego poder recuperarla mediante `fetch_assoc` (esto es cuestión de preferencias, de claridad de código... otros métodos son posibles).
- Usar un operador ternario para asignar a `$maximo` sea `0` si no encuentra datos, sea el valor de la columna obtenida.
- Retornar `$maximo`, como un entero. Lo puedes probar mediante `var_dump($maximo);`.

**NOTA:** He quitado `@`. Es una mala práctica de programación silenciar los errores.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: muchisimas gracias... muy bien explicado como siempre

Comment: @A.Cedano solo como recomendación, no sería mas eficiente hacer una unica conversion a int en el return, es decir `return (int) $maximo`, en lugar de convertir multiples veces.

Comment: Tienes razón @Xerif. Editado con la optimización sugerida.